# Change the pathname in the URL of a link while keeping the querystring constant

Tags: javascript, html, url, query-string, href

From a page with the following URL, `http://example.com/foo.html?query=1&other=2`, I want to create a link to `http://example.com/bar.html?query=1&other=2`. How do I do that without explicitly saving and reloading all the query strings.

I need this to easily link from an iframe version of a page (`embed.html?query`) to the full page (`index.html?query`).

Comment: what do you mean to say that " I want to create a link"?

Comment: I need an anchor `<a href="...">Full page</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have recommended using the [Location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)'s `search` method (available at `document.location` or `window.location`) to pull out the parameters, then modify the rest of the URL, but that API is apparently specific to Firefox.

I would simplify @DMortensen's answer by just splitting on the first `?`, then modifying the first part (which will be the URL's path portion only), and reapplying the second part.

If you need to parse the parameters, I recommend the jQuery plugin [Query Parameter Parser](https://github.com/mattsnider/jquery-plugin-query-parser): one call to `$.parseQuery(s)` will pull out an object of all the keys & values.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. I tried the following and it works.

    `function gotoFullSite() {
        var search = window.location.search;
        window.open("http://example.com/"+search)
    }
    $('#clickable').click(gotoFullSite);`

and the use `<a id = "clickable" href="#"></a>`. When I click the link, it opens the proper website with all the query parameters in a new tab. (I need a new tab to break out of the `iframe` the embed page is in.)

Answer (score 0):

It can be finicky, but you could split the URI on '?' and then loop through the 2nd element of that array to grab the key/val pairs if you need to evaluate each pair (using '&' as a delimiter).  The obvious weakness in this would be if there are additional '?' or '&' used in the URI.

Something like this maybe? (pseudocode-ish)

```
var URI = document.URL;
var qs = URI.split('?');
var keyvalpair = qs[1].split('&');
var reconstructedURI = '&' + keyvalpair;
for(var i = 0; i< keyvalpair.length; i++){
    var key = keyvalpair[i].split('=')[0];
    var val = keyvalpair[i].split('=')[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the answers. I tried the following and it works.

```
function gotoFullSite() {
    var search = window.location.search;
    window.open("http://example.com/"+search)
}
$('#clickable').click(gotoFullSite);
```

and then use `<a id = "clickable" href="#"></a>`. When I click the link, it opens the proper website with all the query parameters in a new tab. (I need a new tab to break out of an `iframe`.)